# The best practice to force x clients to wait for the callback of client y in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, callback, queue

I'm trying to implement a cache system for a data-delivery tool for different clients with node.js.
It's an http-service and I use express to handle the requests. My cache-system needs to support three cases:

**Case 1 - There is no cache:**
The program receives the data via the given get-method. If successful it writes the cache.

**Case 2 - There is a cache:**
The program receives the cache.

**Case 3 - There is no cache but the get-method for the same request was already called by a different client and is currently being processed.** 
The programm needs to wait until the other request received its data via the get-method and deliver the newly written cache.

I solved the problem of "Case 3" with events. I register an event for every client / request combination. But it feels not very elegant to register an open amount of events. Also the use of queues is not one of the best solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you don't need events to implement your cache system, but I don't see how it could be implemented without queues.

Here is how I would implement the cache:

```
var cache = {};

function get(uri, cb) {
  var key = uri; // id of the resource, you might want to strip some URI parts
  var cacheEntry = cache[key];

  if (!cacheEntry)
    cache[key] = cacheEntry = {};

  if (cacheEntry.value) {
     // cache hit - return the cached value
     return process.nextTick(function() { cb(null, cacheEntry.value });
  }

  if (cacheEntry.waiting) {
     // another request is in progress - queue the callback
     cacheEntry.waiting.push(cb);
     return;
  }

  // we are the first client asking for this value
  cacheEntry.waiting = [cb];
  request.get(uri, handleResponse);


  function handleResponse(err, resp, body) {
    // process the response headers and body and save it to the cache
    var content = body;
    cacheEntry.value = content;

    // fire callbacks waiting for the cached value
    if (cacheEntry.waiting) {
      var q = cacheEntry.waiting;
      delete cacheEntry.waiting;
      q.forEach(function(cb) { cb(null, content); })
    }
  }
}
```